# Google Chrome, Sub-Navigation Options Vanish

Tags: google-chrome

Why does three quarters of my sub-navigation vanish in Google Chrome but not in Firefox nor Internet Explorer?

**Steps to recreate the problem:**

1. Open Google Chrome Version 22.0.1229.79 m
2. Navigate to bigfont.ca
3. Click About Us, then Services, then Client List.
4. When you click Client List, the three quarters of the sub-navigation menu disappears.

**Here is what the sub-navigation usually looks like:**

[image]

**Here is how is breaks after steps 1-4:**

[image]

Why does three quarters of the sub-navigation vanish after clicking in a specific sequence?!

**Here are some interesting observations:**

1. After completing steps 1-4 above, I can bring back the missing aspects of the sub-navigation by hovering over where we would expect them to be. They just come back.
2. The problem only occurs in very specific sub-navigation click orders.

**Here are the specific click orders that break it.**

-the last click needs to be Client List

-the second to last click needs to be Services

-the third to last click needs to be something other than Client List.

**Here are some more examples**

About Us > Services > Client List = Vanish

About Us > Services > Services > Client List = Vanish

Shaun Luttin > Services > Client List = Vanish

About Us > Shaun Luttin > Services > Client List = Vanish

About Us > Shaun Luttin > Client List = No Problem!!!

About Us > Client List = No Problem

**What is going on here?**

Comment: This appears to be a known issue in Bootstrap. https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/32 That said, I was unable to recreate the problem with the Bootstrap Docs Sub Navigation. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out. Chrome renders well after we changed our menu element class to **nav-list** NOT **nav-tab**. Go figure.